Where to redeclare bibliography driver for style modification
I'm using Overleaf and biblatex with style=offa (a German archaeology style). I managed to make some small modifications, but now I want to implement something I can't get to work. In the bibliography for an @incollection entry with a crossref to a @collection, I want the @collection to be referenced with a citation (like in: Author 2024, 10-32) instead of reiterating all the information.
In the biblatex manual, I found pretty much that exact case (Section 4.11.7) and wrote a new \DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{...} making use of \iffieldundef{crossref}. Naively, I tried putting that straight in my preamble, which did do something of the sort I wanted, but also messed up a lot of other things. suddenly all @incollection entries, even those without crossref, would cite the same collection and other entry types were also suddenly showing information that had nothing to do with them.
I figure the \DeclareBibliographyDriver should not be placed in the preamble. Where else should I put it, if I don't have the style files locally cause I work on Overleaf? Is there a way to make a little modification .bbx right in my directory or is that even the issue here?
(EDIT:) Here's a reduced version of my .tex file:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=offa,backend=biber,sorting=nyt, mincrossrefs=1]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{
    \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{In:\space}}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{incollection}
    {\iffieldundef{crossref}
        {\addspace}
        {\addcomma\space}}
    {\addcomma\space}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {\usebibmacro{editor+others}%
      \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
      \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{edition}%
      \newunit
      \iffieldundef{maintitle}
        {\printfield{volume}%
         \printfield{part}}
        {}%
      \newunit
      \printfield{volumes}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{series+number}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{note}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
      \newunit\newblock}
    {\cite{\thefield{crossref}}}
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{example}
\author{Lucas Knepper}
\date{July 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\cite{goldmann}\cite{maik}
\printbibliography

\end{document}

with the .bib file looking like this:
@incollection{goldmann,
    crossref = {fansa},
    author = {Annelies Goldmann},
    title = {Das Weben am Rundwebstuhl},
    pages = {427–431}
}

@collection{fansa,
    title = {Experimentelle Archäologie in Deutschland},
    subtitle = {Begleitschrift zu einer Ausstellung des Staatlichen Museums für Naturkunde und Vorgeschichte Oldenburg, 27.5. - 23.9.1990},
    editor = {Mamoun Fansa},
    series = {Archäologische Mitteilungen aus Nordwestdeutschland},
    number = {Beiheft 4},
    year = {1990},
    location = {Oldenburg}
}

@incollection{maik,
    author = {Jerzy Maik},
    title = {Polnische Versuche der Webstuhl-Rekonstruktion},
    booktitle = {Experimentelle Archäologie in Deutschland},
    booksubtitle = {Bilanz 1991},
    editor = {Mamoun Fansa},
    series = {Archäologische Mitteilungen aus Nordwestdeutschland},
    number = {Beiheft 6},
    year = {1991},
    location = {Oldenburg},
    pages = {347–351}
}

It gives this output:

Now, even though Maik 1991 doesn't have a crossref field (so, by my understanding \iffieldundef{crossref} should be false), it still cites Fansa 1990 as it's collection. Where am I going wrong?
(I'm very new to working with biblatex and not at a point where I can pose this question as specifically as probably necessary, sorry...)

\DeclareBibliographyDriver can be placed in the preamble and indeed this is the best (most convenient place) to put it when you play around with that command. It's next to impossible to tell from the details shared so far why things went wrong, though. If you want more concrete help with that, please share a small, compilable example document that shows what you did with as little code as possible. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.

\DeclareBibliographyDriver can be placed anywhere in the preamble (after \usepackage{biblatex}) and usually this is the best (most convenient place) to put it when you play around with that command. Obviously you can move it to a .bbx or some other file later, but that is not at all required.
The problem here was that biblatex-archaeology applies a healthy number of patches to bibdrivers, but when you (re)define a driver those patches are made undone.
In particular your code will need to call \blxarch@settabbedlabeldate{incollection} after the driver is defined and then you also need an explicit \end{tabbedlabeldate} in the <true> branch of \iffieldundef{crossref} since we have an implicit \begin{tabbedlabeldate} there as well (which is hidden in the \usebibmacro{editor+others} call).
The following should work
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=offa,backend=biber,mincrossrefs=1]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{In:\space}}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{incollection}
    {\iffieldundef{crossref}
        {\addspace}
        {\addcomma\space}}
    {\addcomma\space}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {\usebibmacro{editor+others}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
     \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{edition}%
     \newunit
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}}
       {}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{volumes}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{series+number}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{note}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \end{tabbedlabeldate}}
    {\cite{\thefield{crossref}}}
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\makeatletter
\blxarch@settabbedlabeldate{incollection}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{goldmann,
    crossref = {fansa},
    author = {Annelies Goldmann},
    title = {Das Weben am Rundwebstuhl},
    pages = {427–431}
}
@collection{fansa,
    title = {Experimentelle Archäologie in Deutschland},
    subtitle = {Begleitschrift zu einer Ausstellung des Staatlichen Museums für Naturkunde und Vorgeschichte Oldenburg, 27.5. - 23.9.1990},
    editor = {Mamoun Fansa},
    series = {Archäologische Mitteilungen aus Nordwestdeutschland},
    number = {Beiheft 4},
    year = {1990},
    location = {Oldenburg}
}
@incollection{maik,
    author = {Jerzy Maik},
    title = {Polnische Versuche der Webstuhl-Rekonstruktion},
    booktitle = {Experimentelle Archäologie in Deutschland},
    booksubtitle = {Bilanz 1991},
    editor = {Mamoun Fansa},
    series = {Archäologische Mitteilungen aus Nordwestdeutschland},
    number = {Beiheft 6},
    year = {1991},
    location = {Oldenburg},
    pages = {347–351}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{goldmann,maik}
\printbibliography
\end{document}



Thank you so much. That worked. For next time: Where should I look to find information such as the how biblatex-archaeology patches certain drivers?

@LucasKnepper This was incredibly tricky to track down. First I checked that we got the expected result with the standard authoryear style. I then started by looking at offa.bbx and confirmed that only the bibliography style was relevant (by choosing citestyle=authoryear,). From then on I chased down all the files that that file loads and identified which bit of the code caused the problem by copying bits of it to the document preamble (selecting a generic style) and deleting it bit by bit.
